# A contradiction when applying the error estimate in the trapezoidal rule

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

When approximating $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ by the sum of areas of $N$ trapezoids $$T_N=\frac{b-a}{N}\left(\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} f\left(a+k\frac{b-a}{N}\right)\right)$$
the [error term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Error_analysis) satisfies
$$E=\int_a^b f(X) dx - T_N = -\frac{(b-a)^3}{12N^2}f''(\zeta)$$
for $\zeta\in(a,b)$ which maximizes $f''(x)$. (Assuming $f''(x)$ exists and is continuous in this interval.)

What confuses me is that if I try to apply this formula for $\int_1^n \frac{1}{x}dx = \log n$, then sum of areas of the trapezoids is
$$\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{2}+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}$$
which is clearly a rational number, and since on the interval $[1,n]$ the maximum of $f''(x)=\frac{2}{x^3}$ is at $x=1$ then the error is given by
$$E=-\frac{(n-1)^3}{12(n-1)^2}\cdot\frac{2}{1^3}=-\frac{n-1}{6}$$
which is again clearly a rational number, but the integral itself is $\log n$ which is irrational.

Relatedly, the reason I initially tried this calculation is in order to try and get a lower bound for $\gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k} - \log n$ but the above calculation gives me $\gamma>1$ which is absurd.

Clearly I'm doing something silly and misapplying one the formulas above in some way. Where is my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value $\zeta$ need not provide an extreme value for $f''$, it is just some value on the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: But if I'm not making an error in following the proof here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Error_analysis then the value of $\zeta$ is chosen to be the maximum of $f''(x)$, and other sources also seem to claim that this $\zeta$ is the maximum of $f''(x)$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: @Snaw:  the value of  $\zeta$ is chosen to be the maximum when we want to bound the error.  Your equation for the error term should have $\le$, not $=$.  The expression with the exact value for the integral will use some value for $\zeta$ in the interval, but unless we can do the integral in some other way we cannot know which one.

Comment: @RossMillikan I see. I must have been sloppy when reading the proof. Thanks!